# iPhone: Obj C vs JS. Bridge. Send JSON from Obj C to JS

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, sencha-touch

I already asked similar question [iPhone: call and send parameters to JS function from OBJ-C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7555708/602011).
Right now in my JS i have hardcode like:

```
> var data = [];
>             data.push({name: '',samsung: 30.5, genNum: 45.7, lastNum: 78.7});
>             data.push({name: 'Jun',samsung: 45.7,nokia: 45.7, genNum: 70.3});
>             data.push({name: 'Jul',samsung: 70.3,nokia: 70.3, genNum: 60.3});
>             data.push({name: 'Aug',samsung: 60.3,nokia: 60.3, genNum: 64.5});
>             data.push({name: 'Sep',samsung: 64.5,nokia: 64.5});
>             data.push({name: 'Nov',samsung: 78.7,android: 78.7});
>             data.push({name: ' '});
```

But I want to send this date from Obj C. How to do that ? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

```
[mapView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"javascriptname(arguments)"];
```

as is, this works for strings